# Marking nodes in Graph?

Tags: algorithm, depth-first-search, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am currently learning some search algorithms and I am curious to know how would the performance of Depth-first search being effected, if we don't mark the nodes that we have visited (in other words, we re-visit nodes) in a directed acyclic graph?

Comment: The answer is "badly". You would end up with exponential instead of linear time

Comment: @NiklasB. Based on my calculation it will end up visiting 2^n nodes, where n is the number of depth in the graph. is that correct?

Comment: Well the base really depends on the structure of your graph. I guess the worst case is ~2^(n/2)  where n is the number of nodes. In general a node will be visited once for every distinct path that leads to it

Comment: The complexity would be proportional to the number of ways of reaching all other nodes from the start node. By number of ways, I mean the number of different paths (as we don't remember already visited ones).